# Find a matrix B such that $Im_{\phi_{B}}$=$\ker_{\phi_{A}}$ and $\ker_{\phi_{A}}$={0} for a given matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is the matrix $A \in M_{m,n} (\mathbb{F_{2}})$ given by:

\begin{pmatrix} 
  1 & 1 & 0 &1 &1\\ 
  1 & 0 & 1 &1 &0\\
  0 & 1 & 1 &1 &1\\
\end{pmatrix}

Find a matrix $B$ such that such that $Im_{\phi_{B}}$=$\ker_{\phi_{A}}$ and $\ker_{\phi_{A}}$={0}

I know how to find the image and kernel of a matrix but is there a particular 'trick' for this question?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Find a basis for the kernel of $A$ and let those be the rows of the matrix $B$.

Comment: OK, why would this work?

Comment: For the claim about the kernel equaling the image, look at where $B$ maps the standard basis.  For the claim about not having a kernel, just compute the kernel of $B$.  If you want to know *why* it doesn't have a kernel think about how multiplying $B$ by a column vector is equivalent to taking a linear combination of the columns of $B$.